# TRANSFORM Access SQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I ran across a statement in MS Access that I have never seen before and don't know how to convert into SQL Server or exactly what it is doing - can anybody tell me what this is doing and possibly how I would convert into SQL Server?

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Qty) AS SumOfQty
SELECT [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].[Acct Name], [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].[Acct#], [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Material, [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Mth
FROM [Fcst/Order/Ship Data]
WHERE ((([Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Year)=2017) AND (([Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Type)="Open_allocated" Or ([Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Type)="shipment" Or ([Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Type)="forecast"))
GROUP BY [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].[Acct Name], [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].[Acct#], [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Material, [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Mth
PIVOT [Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Type;
```

Comment: Try the Crosstab query wizard.

Comment: thanks - I was curious how or if i could replicate that in SQL Server?  All very new to me

Comment: In SQL Server it is PIVOT: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Transform should present the results in a table like format (kind of excel) using the values of pivot as column headers in the query result.

See [TRANSFORM Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx)